# Update 'nested' javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create an object that is updated dynamically.

Here's the setup of the type of object I'd like to create (note: I may add other things, such as `address`, `country`, etc to the keys):

```
var contacts = {"Bruce Wayne":{"phone number":'123-456-7890', "email":"bwayne@night.com"}, "Alfred":{"phone number" :'987-654-3210', "email": "alfred@yourang.com"}, "Clark Kent":{"phone number":'951-753-8520', "email":"nothing@krypton.com"}}
```

So for each name (`Bruce Wayne`, `Alfred`, ...) I have some keys assigned to them.

I'm using [npm faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker) to generate some fake data to try and populate an array like the above, with the outline

I'm able to get a loop going, but it always returns the last iteration's data.  I understand it's because I'm doing `contact = ...`. Since this is an object, I can't use `push`, AFAIK.

```
function getContact(numContacts){
    contacts = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < numContacts; i++){
        console.log(i);
        var name = faker.name.firstName() + " " + faker.name.lastName();
        var phoneNum = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
        var email = faker.internet.email();
        contacts = {name :{ "phone number": phoneNum, "email": email}}
        // contacts.name = {"phone number": phoneNum, "email":email};  // this also returns just the last instance.
    };
    return contacts;
};

var contacts = getContact(10); // This should create ten people, each with a phone number and email.
```

The loop almost successfully creates a *single* name. This returns:

> name, 761.704.3328 x4287, Leopold81@hotmail.com

But in that iteration, `name` variable is actually `Joe Schmoe`, not literally `name`...

What am I overlooking to make sure that the `contacts` object gets populated with 10 people, with the resolved `name`, not just the last in the iteration?

Comment: To add new property to your object, you need to do `contacts[somePropertyName] = {...}`.  Doing `contacts = {...}` just replaces everything that was previous in the `contacts` object with a whole new object that only has the latest stuff in it.  All previous contents are no longer there in the new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are the keys in your object. You can use it like an array index to populate contacts. This should work:

```
contacts[name] = {"phone number": phoneNum, "email": email}
```

Comment: Man, I struggled so much with this earlier, and I *swear* I tried that, but must have done it wrong at the time. This works, and seems like the easiest/best way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Observations

- You're trying to use `name` variable as key, however, what you're doing is adding a key literally called `name`.
- What you have to do, is to create the key programmatically as follow: `contacts[name]` and assign the object with `phoneNumber` and `Email`.
- This code is an example to simulate your scenario.

```js
var faker = {
  name: {
    firstName: function() {
      return "Clark";
    },
    lastName: function() {
      return "Kent";
    }
  },
  phone: {
    phoneNumber: function() {
      return '951-753-8520';
    }
  },
  internet: {
    "email": function() {
      return "nothing@krypton.com";
    }
  }
};

function getContact(numContacts) {
  var contacts = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < numContacts; i++) {
    var name = faker.name.firstName() + " " + faker.name.lastName();
    var phoneNum = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
    var email = faker.internet.email();

    contacts[name + '_' + i] = {
      "phone number": phoneNum,
      "email": email
    }
  }

  return contacts;
}

var contacts = getContact(10);

console.log(contacts);
```

Comment: All the faker stuff is taken care of by the npm package. I'm learning JavaScript so to me it looks like the main solution you have is the same as the one I selected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Basically, the same answer.  However, I've put some observations to guide you. :-)

Comment: excellent, that's what I thought! I appreciate it, it gives me insight on how to set up my own thing like that in the future. :D